# tab bar controller is not shows the tab buttons after updating xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, tabs, uitabbarcontroller

I was developing an application which uses UI TabBar controllers and I have updated my mac Osx and the Xcode to the version 5.1.1. before these updates , my application worked fine.

now when i run the application after the update, my tab buttons (which should be there at the bottom of the simulator)  do not show. i did not change anything in my project. just above updates only i did. i checked my storyboard to check whether those tab buttons are there. unfortunately they are not there.. the only thing i can see is like the below[image]

before the update my storyboard looked like the following

[image: you can see the tab buttons are there in this picture]

now it looks like this

[image]

you can see in the tab bar controller there are no tab buttons like the above screenshot..

my application is now like this when it runs...

[image]

What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you change all the TabBar item's icon than you can see tabBar.

[image]

Comment: select each tab bar item and changes its identifier or give its image and it done.